# nginx - can proxy caching be configured so files are saved without HTTP headers or otherwise in a more "human friendly" format?

Tags: caching, proxy, nginx

I'm curious if nginx can be configured so the cache is saved out in some manner that would make the data user-friendly?  While all my options might fall short of anything anyone would consider "human friendly" I'm in general interested in how people configure it to meet their specific needs.  The documentation may be complete but I am very much a *learn by example* type guy.

My current configuration is from an example I ran accross and if it were to be used woud  is not much more than proof to me that nginx correctly proxy caches/the data

```
http {    

# unrelated stuff...

proxy_cache_path  /var/www/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path /var/www/cache/tmp; 

server {
    server_name g.sente.cc;
    location /stu/ {
    proxy_pass http://sente.cc;
    proxy_cache my-cache;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
    proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question looks unfinished; _and when I say current setup_. Incidentally, when I used `polipo` caching web proxy once to grab 'raw files' out of an HTTP stream, there were convenient new headers inserted into the file with the starting byte position. It was easy to smack together a little program to find that number and then read just those bytes. Would something similar work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I could process the files as they are saved now with roughly the same amount of work.  The biggest problem with current setup is the directory structure and naming convention, neither of which offer any insight into what's in our cache without running scripts/etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nginx has two methods to cache content:

- `proxy_store` is when Nginx builds a *mirror*. That is, it will store the file preserving the same path, while proxying from the upstream. After that Nginx will serve the mirrored file for all the subsequent requests to the same URI. The downside is that Nginx does not control expiration, however you are able to remove (and add) files at your will.
- `proxy_cache` is when Nginx manages a cache, checking expiration, cache size, etc.